# How to train iOS 8 spellcheck for acronyms?

Tags: ios, spellcheck

In iOS 7, one could train spellcheck to recognize acronyms by, e.g., typing 'My Story (MS)' so that when you subsequently typed 'ms' it would appear as 'MS'. This no longer works -- or, at best, works  occasionally and often forgets.

The iOS 8 advice, e.g., from http://www.wired.com/2014/10/quicktype-tips-ios-8, to select text and double-tap the shift key to get 'all caps' suggestions in QuickType, is tedious and works only occasionally.

How does one train the spellchecker for acronyms in iOS 8?

Answer (score 1):

You can manually add them by using the keyboard shortcuts feature.

Go to Settings > General > Keyboard > Shortcuts then add as many as you want.

It may be a little tedious at the beginning but the settings will stay there forever.

Comment: Thanks -- I should have mentioned that's where I began long ago. Unfortunately, that's so much less convenient than the iOS 7 spellcheck.